# How we can go live as solochain?

Tags: solo-chain

I want to release our chain as solochain. Do we have any checklist or something which help thought the process so that we cannot miss any step or configuration?

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template), you can get a solo chain.

Follow [substrate-parachain-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template), you can get a solo chain.

The checklist is totally up to you. If you prefer to use `AURA` or `BABE` as your chain's consensus engine, ensure that those configurations are checked. Verify your genesis validators and other relevant items on the list.

---

Basically:

1. runtime pallets
2. pallets' configurations
3. genesis

These are the most important/basic things.

Comment: What does `Verify your genesis validators` means @AurevoirXavier? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The validator id and the session keys. If you set it wrong, your new chain can not produce any block.

Answer (score 0):

you can also check out Aleph Zero node repository here: https://github.com/Cardinal-Cryptography/aleph-node for how we set up both node and runtime (we are running solo-chain mainnet for 1.5 years now)